# How to set a scrollView to half of screen with ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, layout, scrollview, android-constraintlayout

I have a `ConstraintLayout` with some view itens and a `listView` to show some values. I need to create a layout with HALF SCREEN and in the first layout i need to use a `scrollView`, to complete all infos and register. Can i set layout to half of screen with no using a fixing `layout_height`?

**This is my layout, with a fixed layout_height :**

[image: This is my layout, with a fixed layout_height]

and this is my layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"

    android:id="@+id/myScrollView">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtViewExpense"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/expense"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtExpenseValue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtViewExpense" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtViewPrice"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/expense_price"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtExpenseValue" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtViewPriceValue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtViewPrice" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtViewCategory"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/expense_category"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtViewPriceValue" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spnCategory"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtViewCategory" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtViewFrequency"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/expense_frequency"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spnCategory" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spnFrequency"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtViewFrequency" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtViewExpenseDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/expense_date"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spnFrequency" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtExpenseDateValue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="date"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtViewExpenseDate" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnExpenseDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Button"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.509"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/txtExpenseDateValue"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtViewExpenseDate" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Button"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtExpenseDateValue" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

  </ScrollView>

  <com.baoyz.swipemenulistview.SwipeMenuListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewExpense"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/myScrollView" />





    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Any one can help me? Thx o/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the outer ConstraintLayout to LinearLayout. Then you have to set the layout weight to ScrollView and ListView. Layout weight will be `1` for these two views. So that, these views can be equally divided into the screen. This will be the updated code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/myScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtViewExpense"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtExpenseValue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtViewExpense" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtViewPrice"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtExpenseValue" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtViewPriceValue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtViewPrice" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtViewCategory"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtViewPriceValue" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spnCategory"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtViewCategory" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtViewFrequency"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spnCategory" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spnFrequency"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtViewFrequency" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtViewExpenseDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spnFrequency" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtExpenseDateValue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="date"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtViewExpenseDate" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnExpenseDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="Button"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.509"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/txtExpenseDateValue"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtViewExpenseDate" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="Button"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtExpenseDateValue" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <com.baoyz.swipemenulistview.SwipeMenuListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewExpense"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/myScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtViewExpense"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtExpenseValue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtViewExpense" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtViewPrice"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtExpenseValue" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtViewPriceValue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtViewPrice" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtViewCategory"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtViewPriceValue" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spnCategory"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtViewCategory" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtViewFrequency"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"

                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spnCategory" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spnFrequency"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtViewFrequency" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtViewExpenseDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"

                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spnFrequency" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtExpenseDateValue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="date"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtViewExpenseDate" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnExpenseDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="Button"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.509"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/txtExpenseDateValue"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtViewExpenseDate" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="Button"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtExpenseDateValue" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </ScrollView>


    <com.baoyz.swipemenulistview.SwipeMenuListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewExpense"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/myScrollView" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do it is to add a `Guideline` to your root `ConstraintLayout` at 50% of its height and constrain the bottom of the `ScrollView` to it and the top to the parent:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/myScrollView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtViewExpense"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/expense"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtExpenseValue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtViewExpense" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtViewPrice"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/expense_price"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtExpenseValue" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtViewPriceValue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtViewPrice" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtViewCategory"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/expense_category"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtViewPriceValue" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spnCategory"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtViewCategory" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtViewFrequency"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="@string/expense_frequency"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spnCategory" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spnFrequency"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtViewFrequency" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtViewExpenseDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="@string/expense_date"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spnFrequency" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtExpenseDateValue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="date"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtViewExpenseDate" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnExpenseDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="Button"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.509"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/txtExpenseDateValue"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtViewExpenseDate" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="Button"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtExpenseDateValue" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <com.baoyz.swipemenulistview.SwipeMenuListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewExpense"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/myScrollView" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Guideline and put it in middle of screen and set your scrollview to above it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/myScrollView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/gl1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtViewExpense"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="expense"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtExpenseValue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtViewExpense" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtViewPrice"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="expense_price"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtExpenseValue" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtViewPriceValue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtViewPrice" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtViewCategory"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="expense_category"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtViewPriceValue" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spnCategory"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtViewCategory" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtViewFrequency"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="expense_frequency"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spnCategory" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spnFrequency"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtViewFrequency" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtViewExpenseDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="expense_date"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spnFrequency" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtExpenseDateValue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="date"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtViewExpenseDate" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnExpenseDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="Button"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.509"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/txtExpenseDateValue"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtViewExpenseDate" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="Button"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtExpenseDateValue" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/gl1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

    <com.baoyz.swipemenulistview.SwipeMenuListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewExpense"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/gl1" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```